# Number of times a product is ordered in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product which belongs to multiple categories in woocommerce. I want to generate a custom report i.e. sales by category. I want to show it separately that how many times the product was ordered in Category ! and how many times in Category B. Is it some thing possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we aren't going to do it for you even if you had provided enough information to do so.  Show what you have tried.  Also this will be quite complicated since you need to track referral paths (since a product with multiple categories does not "belong" to either one of them, so to determine which category it was ordered from requires tracking the user's behavior on the site).

Comment: Bro I didnt asked you to do it for me. I will do it myself :-) Thanks for your comments